# Commutator of gamma matrices with scalar product of 4-vectors

Tags: commutator, dirac-matrices

I know about the commutator relationship given in this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/144485/commutator-of-dirac-gamma-matrices):
$$\left[\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}\right]=2\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}-2\eta^{\mu\nu}$$
then, my question is if there exist a similar relationship for the following
$$\left[\gamma \cdot p,\gamma\cdot q\right] $$
where $p$ and $q$ are 4-vectors,
I have tried solve it using the following Dirac Salsh relation
$${a\!\!\!/}{b\!\!\!/}=\left[a\cdot b-ia_{\mu }\sigma ^{\mu \nu }b_{\nu }\right]$$
where $\sigma^{\mu\nu}=\frac{i}{2}\left[\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}\right]$, thus
$$\left[\gamma \cdot p,\gamma\cdot q\right]=i\left(q_{\mu}\sigma^{\mu\nu}p_{\nu}-p_{\mu}\sigma^{\mu\nu}q_{\nu}\right)$$
therefore, **is $\left[\gamma \cdot p,\gamma\cdot q\right]=0$?**

Comment: What prevents you from writing $[\gamma \cdot p,\gamma \cdot q] = [\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu]p_\mu q_\nu$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write $[\gamma\cdot p,\gamma\cdot q] = [\gamma^\mu p_{\mu}, \gamma^\nu q_{\nu}]$ then you can treat $p_{\mu}$ and $q_{\nu}$ as just numbers, i.e. they are "scalars" with respect to the spinor indices of the gamma matrices and can be pulled out of the commutator.

Then we can use your result $[\gamma^\mu p_{\mu}, \gamma^\nu q_{\nu}] = p_\mu q_\nu [\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu] = p_\mu q_\nu (2\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu - 2\eta^{\mu\nu}) = 2{\not}p{\not}q - 2 p\cdot q$

where I've used the slash notation to imply ${\not}p = \gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you tell me why my question are not correct?

Comment: your last equation isn't 0 because the momenta are being contracted with different indices, $q$ is contracted with the first index in the first term and the 2nd index in the 2nd term, so they don't cancel.